# Access user control type from a dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control (under a website project)

**UcArticle.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" 
            AutoEventWireup="true"
            CodeFile="UcArticle.ascx.cs" 
            Inherits="Uc_UcArticle" 
            ViewStateMode="Disabled" %>
...
```

And the code Behind is  :

**UcArticle.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class Uc_UcArticle : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
   ...
}
```

However , I have a **DLL** project and a  method inside it which should use the type `UcArticle`  :

```
  public void AddMethod(UcArticle uc ) //error here
        {
         //do something with uc...

        }
```

But the dll doesn't know `UcArticle` ( Cannot resolve symbol)

*p.s. I could use `dynamic` to access the properties of uc  , but I don't want to do that.*

How can I make the dll know the type `UcArticle` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i think this is a bad design.

In you AddMethod function, do you really need your customized user control type?
why not declare an interface, make your customized user control implements the interface,
also change the AddMethod function to carry the interface type as parameter. just expose whatever operation you want to outside.

what do you think?

updated(i just type directly here, so, sorry for the format):

```
//well then you can declare the interface as:
public interface ITextControl{
 string TextValue{get;set}
}
//and in your code:
public partical class whateveryourcontrolname:UserControl,ITextControl
{
/..../
public string TextValue{
 get{
  return this.Text;
 }
set{
 this.Text=value;
 }
}
}
//and your method:
void AddMethod(ITextControl txtCtrl){
 txtCtrl.TextValue="Yes";
}
```

Comment: Yes I really need to get its type cuz im later doing ( `uc.MyProp.Text=...`) and `MyProp` belongs to the type...

Comment: _"Yes I really need to ..."_ - Whatever you want to do, there are always many ways to do it. The way you have chosen here leads to spaghetti hell.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a project that contains a UC and the project depends on an assembly that needs the UC, then you have a circular dependency.

The best way to break this is to put the UC in yet another, separate, assembly.

But it remains a smell that any part of your business logic should need to know about a piece of the UI. So do rethink the design that leads you here. Something's rotten.

Comment: But I have a web site  , where should i declare the UC ? in another website ?

Comment: In an assembly (class library). I don't remember if there's a ready-made template but just adding a few references should do the trick.

Comment: I never heard about creating a user control in a dll project. ( im using a website and not webapplication)

Comment: The website angle make it a little more fuzzy but the answer stands. Just try it.